# Update matrix onBeforeSaveUser

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, craft-pro, updates

I have a matrix block attached to my user, the block handler is children and has one field dob date filed something like this:

```
fields[children][420][fields][childrenDateOfBirth][date]
```

The problem is that I would like to update the date right before the user is saved. So I have an envent listener in my plugin

```
craft()->on('users.onBeforeSaveUser', function(Event $event) {

    $matrixData = array();
    $matrix     = $event->params['user']->getContent()->children;

      foreach ($matrix as $block){

        $blockData = array(
                            'type' => $block->getType()->handle,
                            'enabled' => $block->enabled
                           );   

         $blockData['fields'] = array(
                           'childrenDateOfBirth' => array('date'=>'2000-10-10')
                        );

          $matrixData[$block->id] = $blockData;                                     

  }

 $event->params['user']->getContent()->children = $matrixData;

}
  ...............
```

And I get this error : `Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getType() on array` Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you `var_dump($block);die()`; what is it? Is `children` the name of the Matrix field or is that the name of a Matrix block type?

Comment: Thank you Brad for your support, If I understood right, you wanted me to dump
`foreach ($matrix as $block){
    var_dump($block);die();`
so the $block seems to be `object(Craft\MatrixBlockModel)` I was following this example: https://gist.github.com/brandonkelly/8149062 My guess is in that $matrixData is an array, but `$event->params['user']->getContent()->children` expects some kind of object with `getType()` method, but I'm not sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the trick so here is the code if it can help someone else

```
craft()->on('users.onBeforeSaveUser', function(Event $event) {

   $matrixData = array();
   $matrix     = $event->params['user']->getContent()->children;

   foreach ($matrix as $block){

      $block->getContent()->childrenDateOfBirth = '2000-10-10';
      $matrixData[$block->id] = $block;                                     

   }

   $event->params['user']->getContent()->children = $matrixData;

}
```